# Provide dynamic argument list for Django's queryset only()

Tags: python, django, list

I would like to provide [Django's queryset only() function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#only) with a dynamic list of fields.
In a view, you can manually write sth. like

```
queryset = self.model.objects.only('id', 'name', 'someotherfield')
```

However, I want to make this view (it's a view which lists all objects of a model in a table, but only the 4 or 5 fields of the model I choose) generic so that other views subclass this view and can provide a parameter with the list of fields of the respective model that should be displayed in the table.

But if I have the above example rewritten like

```
queryset = self.model.objects.only(self.display_list)
```

and display_list is given as

```
display_list = ['id', 'name', 'latitude', 'longitude']
```

it won't work, I get a "unhashable type: 'list'" TypeError.

It must be somehow possible to provide a list of arguments for the only() function with a parameter, but how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
queryset = self.model.objects.only(*self.display_list)
```

The `*` means "unpack this list and use its items as arguments". See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-operator-mean-in-python) for an explanation.

Comment: Ahhh, now the scales fall from my eyes. Sure! Thanks a lot. I thought I understood *args and **kwargs, now I do better. :)